# Adding objects to Firebase arrays that don't exist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to create this sort of data-structure in Firebase.

```
"updates": {
    "place_id_1": [
        "update1": {},
        "update2": {}
    ],
    "place_id_2": [
        "update1": {},
        "update2": {}
    ]
}
```

And this is the code I'm using, but getting an error `TypeError: updates.$child is not a function(…)`. Not sure what the problem is. Does Firebase create objects/paths if they don't exist when you try to add to them?

```
    var ref = new Firebase(FirebaseConfig.baseUrl + "/updates");
    var updates = $firebaseObject(ref);
    updates.$child(update.place_id).$push(update); // will this work?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$child()` and `$push` are not methods in AngularFire. I highly recommend that you read the [quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html) and [step-by-step guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide) for AngularFire. A few hours spent in the documentation prevents hundreds of questions here.

To create the structure you're looking for you can use AngularFire, but you don't need it.

With the Firebase JavaScript SDK:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FirebaseConfig.baseUrl + "/updates");
var place1 = ref.push();
place1.push({ key: 'value1' });
place1.push({ key: 'value2' });
var place2 = ref.push();
place2.push({ key: 'value3' });
place2.push({ key: 'value4' });
```

With AngularFire:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FirebaseConfig.baseUrl + "/updates");
var place1 = $firebaseArray(ref.push());
place1.$add({ key: 'value1' });
place1.$add({ key: 'value2' });
var place2 = $firebaseArray(ref.push());
place2.$add({ key: 'value3' });
place2.$add({ key: 'value4' });
```

Note that reading a nested array like this will be tricky with AngularFire. This is one reason the Firebase documentation recommends against nesting arrays.

Comment: Thanks Frank - I can't access those docs as the firebase site is blocked but I found $child and $push by looking at other tuts on the internet. Im'm slightly confused with your code, why can't I just add the update object (json) into the array directly?

Comment: `$firebaseArray(ref.child(update.place_id)).$add(update)`? Or `ref.child(update.place_id)).push(update)` (same thing).

Comment: Hi - so I tried the suggested thing and now im trying to preview the data using the query url: https://testapp.firebaseio.com/updates.json. it seems to make the value of the place_id an object (rather than an array)     >>>JSON>>>    


{
    "71a57e17cbfd0f524680221b9896d88c5ab400b3": {
        "-KAeq-rYX2ScaqqeoGZM": {
            "place_id": "71a57e17cbfd0f524680221b9896d88c5ab400b3",
            "username": "test3@test.com",
            "validFrom": 1455638974143,
        }
    }
}

Comment: That is correct. Arrays don't scale well in a distributed system. so Firebase generates its own "array indexes" when you call `push()`. They're the things starting with `-K`. Much as I love to help, it's going to be difficult to efficiently help you if you don't have access to the documentation.

Comment: oh sweet - that makes sense. Is there any way to over-ride the array index with a value I generate?